# How to exit to external site on click of powerapp button and close powerapp window

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

Is there any way to exit powerapp and navigate to external site like sharepoint , currently it redirect me to powerapp home page using below exit() fucntion

```
Exit(launch("http://sharepoint.com"))
```

Comment: Check [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/exit-and-return-to-custom-destination/td-p/38845). Answer is given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that will work.

[Exit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-exit) function in PowerApps

> The [Exit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-exit) function exits the currently running app. The user is
>   returned to the list of apps, where they can select another app to
>   open.

**Syntax**

```
Exit()
```

And currently it only accepts one parameter, boolean value of logout.

```
Exit(Logout)
```

For example, Exit(true), which then would have the app automatically log out the current user and navigate to the login screen of PowerApps.

**A workaround here is:**

Add a launch function before the Exit(), specify the SharePoint Address within the Launch(), for example:

```
Launch("https://powerusers.microsoft.com");Exit(true)
```

This would open a new webpage of the SharePoint page, not the original one.

[Source](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/exit-and-return-to-custom-destination/td-p/38845)

Comment: If this answer helps you then please upvote and accept it as an answer so that it will help others in the future.

Comment: exit true land me on powerapp home page any possibilty to redirect  to sharepoint page or any other external page

Comment: Kindly try the work around approach which I have mentioned in my answer

Comment: i tried above ,it open sharepoint site on new page and current page load to powerapp homepage

Comment: That's the only workaround available. That's how Microsoft has designed the functionality too.